# Python - group by overlapping times

Tags: python

I have lists of tuples, indicating `start time` and `end time`:

```
[('160000', '163559'),
 ('160000', '161359'),
 ('161700', '162959'),
 ('163000', '163159'),
 ('163200', '163559'),
 ('164000', '164159'),
 ('164200', '164459'),
 ('164500', '164759'),
 ('165500', '165859')]
```

(The first tuple means from `16:00:00` to `16:35:59`, and so on)

The time resolution is 1 minute.

What I need to do is to sum up the total sum of the minutes, by how many times those minutes are in the list.

For example, for the first 2 tuples, the minutes between `160000` and `161359` occur twice, and the minutes between `161400` and `163559` occur once, thus the output should be:

```
1: 22
2: 14
```

(22 minutes (from `161400` to `163559`) occur once and 14 minutes (from `160000` and `161359`) occur twice).

The final output from the list above should be:

```
1: 48
2: 33
```

I tried to think in the direction of splitting the data to minutes, and use group by or something like that, but this is clearly very inefficient.